# Style.css bugs the page when i edit it

Tags: html, css

Well i got style.css which it includes in all pages a logo . I'm intrested only to include the logo in one page , so the idea is to edit a copy of Style.css and call it in the script .
Well in pages i got it called like this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" media="all">
```

We have in style.css

```
.body1 {
background:url(../images/bg_img2.png) no-repeat;
width:262px;
height:397px;
position:absolute;
top:0;
right:6px;
z-index:2;
}
```

when i delete these lines cause i want to remove the logo , save it as style1.css
and call in the script using this line

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style1.css" type="text/css" media="all">
```

it bugs the pages and deletes all the design , like i have deleted the whole script (like this https://ibb.co/fOsAXz ) 
i don't think it's needed to upload the whole css , but in request i'll , please help me i'm frozen

Comment: so you have style.css on all pages and only on one page you have style.css  and style1.css and it doesn't work?

Comment: Why delete it if it is not on one page - you may as well use the same stylesheet as it will be cached (and therefore better loading times) and then just not include the element with that class on the page you do not want it on

Comment: What do you mean by "call in the script"?

Comment: Call = Link it to the script , Pete i really don't know how

Answer (score 0):

What if you just don't include `.body1` class to the page you don't wan't to have the logo ?